# How to locate the source file of data retrieved with data("dataset")?

Tags: r, dataset

How can I change, or at least, how can I see where from the source folder a data is being retrieved from when calling `data("dataset")`?
I'm trying to modify the behavior of an R package for educational purposes but I'm stuck changing some data to introduce the values I want, I find .rda files that are called the same, but they seem not to be the ones the data is coming from when `data("dataset")` is called.

I tried exploring all folders and the files on the appData where the library after building and installing is stored but I'm not able to find It.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question? https://r-pkgs.org/data.html

Comment: If you run `as.data.frame(data()$results)` you can get a list of all the dataset names and what packages they come from. They are generally stored in the `/data` folder for the installed package. You can find that path with `system.file(package="dplyr", "data")` for example.